# How do I run a query to replace text with wildcard variables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Normally, I would run the following to replace text within a table in my MySQL database:

```
UPDATE post SET pagetext = REPLACE(pagetext, '[TEXT1]', '[TEXT2]')
```

But how do you replace text that is followed by an alphanumeric set of characters?

This is what I'm trying to replace:

```
[TEXT:12345678] will be replaced with [TEXT]
[/TEXT:12345678] will be replaced with [/TEXT]
```

How do I run the above query with some wildcard variables so anything with

```
[TEXT:********]
```

will be replaced with

```
[TEXT]
```

Forgive my ignorance, but I would like to run this through phpmyadmin - but how do I rewrite the REPLACE portion to accommodate the variables following the text?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes, you will have to use regular expression here.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I would like to run this through phpmyadmin - but how do I rewrite the REPLACE portion to accommodate the variables following the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Daniel try to do this and you will solve your problem :**

1. Export your table into a .SQL file using the EXPORT function from
   the `phpMyAdmin` panel.
2. Using `sed` command in `linux` replace your tags using it's
   wildcard(.)
3. Run the replace command:
   `cat post_table.sql | sed 's/latex:......../latex/g' > post_table_complete_output.sql`
4. Then import the output file in your database.

Done.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I would like to run this through phpmyadmin - but how do I rewrite the REPLACE portion to accommodate the variables following the text?

Comment: give me an example of what text you wanna replace with what text !

Comment: [TEXT:########] will be replaced with [TEXT]

Comment: this is going to be dynamic or is going to be the same pattern ?

Comment: Only those hash tags represent the dynamic data. There are 8 alphanumeric characters followed by the static pattern. Some examples of what I'm trying to replace - [TEXT:12345678] 
[TEXT:abcdefgh] 
[TEXT:a1b2c3b4] 
[TEXT:95720584] 
[TEXT:3ahfba32] 
[TEXT:bc92b20c]

Comment: Ok. I will try to use that substring within my replace query. Are you on any messenger programs? If I can get this to work, I'm happy to pay you for your help, as I really need to get this to work! Trying it now...

Comment: Oh boy. That didn't work. That replaced everything with the output of text. (sigh)

Comment: I'm restoring the database (I'm glad I did a backup). When I go into phpmyadmin and run your query, you're right it returns [TEXT] but I need to use it in conjunction with the search and replace the text for a given table within my database.

Comment: @Daniel - to start with STOP testing in your working Environment!!! bad practice - replicate that db and play with it !!!

Comment: you where missing the where clause !